# Opacity !important doesn't work

Tags: html, css, opacity

Here is my code:

```
<tr style="opacity: 0.5;"><td><img style="opacity: 1.0 !important;" src="/img/crap.png"/><div>Some text, etc...</td></tr>
```

I wan't the image to be showed with full opacity, and rest should be only 50% opacity, I've tried also with `!important` attribute, but it doesn't work. I've tried also to move that styles to the class in the css file. Image always has 50% of opacity.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I believe this article should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696364/translucent-background-color-with-opaque-border

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon thanks :-) please post an answer with that.. so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an existing question about the same problem with yours.

The link is coming here : [Set div's background transparent but not the borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696364/translucent-background-color-with-opaque-border)

The strategy is using CSS "background" properties with color and opacity:

```
background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.4)
```

A good article about rgba can be found here : [CSS RGBA](http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/)

Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the table row has an opacity of `0.5` then setting the opacity of the `<img>` just sets it to `1.0` (or 100%) of `0.5`, the opacity of one if it's ancestors.

You'll need to set the table row opacity to `1.0` to make this work.

Comment: But I wan't the background of table row to have 50% of opacity.

Comment: Then the `<img>` will simply have to be outside of the `<tr>`; otherwise it will always (correctly) have the same opacity as it's ancestors.

Comment: Um yea, but this is not an answer. I know I'll have to set the table row opacity to 1.0 to make this work, so your solution (can't find any btw.) don't help.

Comment: It is an answer. The `<img>` must be outside of the `<tr>`. Use `position:absolute;` on the `<img>` and `position:relative` on a container around your table. Put the `<img>` inside the container and tweak its `left` and `top` to place it exactly where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Clive's answer explains it well.

A work around the issue is explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is relative to the parent element's opacity (unfortunately). So by setting 0.5 opacity on the tr, every child element will have at MOST 0.5 opacity... unless you use rgba:

```
tr {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* RGBa with 0.5 opacity */
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000); /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)"; /* For IE 8*/
}
```

Then everything on top will have whtever opacity you set.

Comment: It fails, because I want to use my own background color on certain table row:/