# Keeping button opacity full when parent div fades out

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started building a website for one of my friends art projects and all has been good until now. I am using jQuery to make my bootstrap jumbotron fadeOut to 0.6 opacity when you hover, as well as making a new div with a button. The issue I am having is that when I hover over the jumbotron, it fades out and the button appears, however the button is also opaque. Please help me, I just recently finished the jQuery course on codecademy and am really excited to continue using it.

js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rsgf7w3u/

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.jumbotron').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.jumbotron').stop().fadeTo('fast', .6);
    $('.jumbotron').prepend('<div id="view-gallery"><button>View Gallery</button></div>');

});
$('.jumbotron').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.jumbotron').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('#view-gallery').remove();
});
```

});

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
background-image:url("mc.jpg");
height:400px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;

}
#view-gallery button {
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:#2F2D30;
border-radius:1px;
border:none;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: Not possible using CSS. `opacity` affects all children/descendants of an element and **cannot** be overridden. You need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Do you know of another way that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opacity isn't easily overriden - you can try the rgba trick. I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rsgf7w3u/4/

```
background-color:rgba(47,45,48);
```

Reference: [Opacity !important doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700686/opacity-important-doesnt-work)